# ¿Por que livewire se carga como texto dentro del body?

Tags: php, laravel, livewire

Obtengo el siguiente problema al pasar mi código de la máquina de pruebas al servidor de producción a través de un pull request (merge). Esto quiere decir que en mi maquina funciona bien, pero en produccion (App DigitalOcean) No.

[image: Problema, muestra tag dentro del render]

El código es el siguiente

```
    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    @livewireStyles
</head>
```

Como ven agrego correctamente la línea @livewireStyles entre los tag `<head> y </head>`, al hacer una inspección me muestra lo siguiente:

[image: carga la línea en el body]

Me carga el @livewireStyle en el body.

**Ya he hecho lo siguiente:**

1- Cambiar de @livewireStyles a @livewireStyles()
2- Borrar la cache del directorio bootstrap/cache
3- He hecho composer install y update
4- php artisan optimize:clear
5- composer dumpautoload y php artisan config:cache
6- Cargué el proyecto funcionando de mi máquina de pruebas a una nueva instancia de App de DO, con las mismas variables de entorno de mi máquina, mismo composer.json, todo funciona menos el Livewire.

Nada con buenos resultados.

Agradezco cualquier guía u orientación.

Comment: no has validado que este funcionando correctamente: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/testing

Comment: ok, voy a revisar y les comento, aunque en mi maquina hago uso del componente y funciona, haciendo consultas al mysql y retornando datos en las vistas..es al moemnto de pasarlo a la maquina en DO que deja de funcionar.

Comment: es posible que la maquina en DO no sea una imagen de tu maquina... incluso es lo mas probable... que existan diferencias de configuración que provoquen mal funcionamientos no esperados...

Comment: Cree una máquina nueva, y me sale lo mismo...No me toma el @livewireStyles del head..me lo muestra como texto plano en el body...trate de usarlo sin blade, pero aparece igual....no se que podrá ser.

Comment: no me entendiste nada de lo que te dije...

Comment: Disculpa, solo para aclarar no es un droplet, es la función App de Digital Ocean, le cargo los mismos env de mi máquina local y obviamente es el mismo composer.

Comment: estoy tratando de ayudarte a hacer el debug la idea es validar que si livewire esta instaldo correctamente, a mi me parece que no... pero tambien veo que no haces en intento de investigar que sucede con tu livewire en ese otro servidor...

Comment: Si, gracias, sigo investigando y descartando elementos del servidor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solucioné el problema de Livewire en el servidor de producción.

La solución fue:

1- Eliminar el archivo composer.lock de mi máquina y del servidor.
2- Ejecutar `composer update` en mi máquina para generar un nuevo composer.lock y ese archivo nuevo desplegarlo en el servidor de producción.
3- Ejecutar `composer install --no-dev`

Saludos y gracias!